# Drawing a vertical line for every non-zero value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to make vertical lines for every non-zero value in a dataframe. I created a small dataframe using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(100,1)))
```

And I tried to create a plot with a vertical line in every place there is a 1, and not a zero by:

```
graph = plt.figure(1)
plt.axvline(x = df)
graph.show()
```

But, I get this error:
"ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Using [`axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(100,1)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.values != 0:
        ax.axvline(x = i)

plt.show()
```

Using [`vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(100,1)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = df.index.values[(df.values[:,0] > 0)]
ax.vlines(x, 0,1, transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform() )

plt.show()
```

Comment: Awesome! I tried adding a legend for this, but it made a legend item for every separate line. Would you know how to only create one legend item that represents the lines as a whole?

Comment: In the first case you need to create the legend manually. In the second case it works out of the box using `label`.